# TYPO3 Class Gpi\Controller\gpiController does not exist. Reflection failed

Tags: composer-php, typo3

After I've installed my TYPO3 extension I faced this issue. I did the research for this issue. I found these solutions but none worked for me:

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59376814/controller-does-not-exist-reflection-failed-typo3)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564713/controller-does-not-exist-reflection-failed-typo3-v2)

[image]

here is my composer

```json
{
    "name": "GlobalizationPartners/Gpi",
    "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
    "description": "",
    "keywords": [
        "TYPO3 CMS",
        "extension"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "GlobalizationPartners\\Gpi\\": "public/typo3conf/ext/gpi/Classes/"
        }
    },
    "license": ["GPL-2.0-or-later"],
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms-core": ">=8.7.0,<11.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "composer", "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/" }
    ]
}
```

here is my controller

```php
<?php
namespace GlobalizationPartners\Gpi\Controller;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;

class gpiController extends ActionController
{
    /**
     * Default action for backend module
     *
     * @return object
     * @since 5.2.0
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\GlobalizationPartners\Gpi\Backend\gpiModule::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would change the file to `GpiController.php` and the class to `gpiController` and every usage

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where's the code that loads the class `Gpi\Controller\gpiController`? The code you've share uses other namespaces

Comment: I think the namespace is correct @NicoHaase

Comment: @GeorgRinger I did this but nothing change still same

Comment: did you add your extension by hand, or with composer?

Comment: no by hand as you mention I created files in (ext) folder and install it

Comment: "I think the namespace is correct" - what do you mean by that? Can you share more details, like the code that defines that class?